# How do I get google checkout to redirect to item specific page after customer placed order?

Tags: java, google-checkout

At the moment after the order is placed and the user click to return they go to my business site url as defined in my checkout profile. But I have two different items on two different webpages how can I get Google checkout to return to a different page for a different item.

Im using  Xml and the Java google-checkout-2-5-1 sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably noticed, there is no automatic re-direct for the buyer after the Google Checkout transaction finishes. The buyer has to **click** on a provided link to navigate back to the seller's site.

You can **programatically** provide a link for the buyer to click and get back to your site after completing the order. Using the Checkout API you can change this URL for every order. See the continue_url paramenter:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Parameter_Reference.html#tag_continue-shopping-url